# Memory Alloc Space / Leak Problem in Golang

Tags: go, cryptography, amazon-ecs, encode

We are facing a memory leak in golang rest api + ecs which can be fixed only after restart.

Problem :

memory does not go above 0.7. At 0.7 memory  Go App stops responding and we have to restart it.

[image]

**What we Tried **

We first time tried pprorf and tried alloc space. because this is rest api, we are returning encrypted json. We have doubt on encyption method used for this problem and want help if we are in the right direction.

**Suspected Code and what we tried**

```
        dashboard := make(map[string]interface{})
    dashboard["feature_banner"] = l_feature_data
    dashboard["home_category"] = home_category_data
    res["dashboard"] = dashboard

    mres, _ := json.Marshal(res)
    ress := ""
    ress = util.EncryptDatas(string(mres))
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"code": 1, "result": ress})
```

```
func EncryptDatas(data string) string {
    bKey := []byte(key)
    bIV := []byte(iv)
    bPlaintext := PKCS5PaddingNew([]byte(data), aes.BlockSize, len(data))
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(bKey)
    if err != nil {
    }
    ciphertext := make([]byte, len(bPlaintext))
    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, bIV)
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, bPlaintext)
    return hex.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
}
```

1. Alloc Space -> EncryptDatas + String(res) : 2493.72MB, 93.06% of 2679.79MB - https://ibb.co/wdrKD0T
2. Alloc Space -> Without EncryptDatas + String(res) both : 1256.06MB, 87.43% of 1436.63MB :  https://ibb.co/t3yTR05
3. Alloc Space -> only String(res) : 1692.63MB, 91.61% of 1847.71MB total :  https://ibb.co/7N84yMS

We are seeking help on following :

1. Are we on right track to find the problem ? Never did pprof before.
2. Encryption is causing the problem ? hex.EncodeToString can be the issue
3. can we manually clean the heap/memory in golang for stopping it to 0.7

Also this is not a problem with particular api.

Comment: alloc_space is an ever increasing counter. It does not represent memory usage. Look at in_use instead.

Comment: Also try viewing the flame graph instead of the normal graph. It'll be much clearer where memory is sitting proportionally.

Comment: If you have a leak, it's probably via goroutines and the stack trace will be of more help. If you want to control GC, then. you need to read https://go.dev/doc/gc-guide. If you are simply using too much memory which is the most likely scenario, you need to put limits on the size of data and or concurrent operations.